# Want buttons in one row, not multiple

Tags: html, css

My buttons currently looks like this

[See here](http://pokit.org/get/?14e81f378ba89a328957b51420f6a212.jpg)

I want to set them all in one row :( 
Where is the problem

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-6" id="div1">
<div class="md-content">
    <div>
        <button class="btn-3">Sehr-Gut</button>
        <button class="btn-4">Gut</button>
        <button class="btn-5">Befriedigend</button>
        <button class="btn-6">Ausreichend</button>
        <button class="btn-7">Mangelhaft</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="mjesto" id="mjesto"> 
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
 .md-modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 630px;
        min-width: 320px;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 2000;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }


    .md-content {
        color: #fff;
        background: #e74c3c;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: did you try `display:inline`, `display:inline-block`, or `float:left` on the buttons?

Comment: The code you've provided isn't enough to figure out why your buttons aren't displaying in one row. With what you've given, everything should work after md-modal is shown. Where is the code that shows md-modal and sets the elements' colour, and where is the rest of the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
/* visibility: hidden; */
```

to

```
text-align: center;
```

or

```
.md-content [class^=btn]{ display:inline-block}
```

## [***-DEMO-***](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/gX45x/)

Full Code looks like this:

```
 .md-modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 630px;
        min-width: 320px;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 2000;
        /* visibility: hidden; */
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }


    .md-content {
        color: #fff;
        background: #e74c3c;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Html:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-6" id="div1">
<div class="md-content">
    <div>
        <button class="btn-3">Sehr-Gut</button>
        <button class="btn-4">Gut</button>
        <button class="btn-5">Befriedigend</button>
        <button class="btn-6">Ausreichend</button>
        <button class="btn-7">Mangelhaft</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="mjesto" id="mjesto"> 
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change visibility because it pop up on button click. Even when i set the text align to center it looks like this [Example](http://pokit.org/get/?3e30520f3825aeba3f017a48c4f481f2.jpg)

Entire page here [page](http://gamersreunion.net/Project/v1.0.html)

Comment: then use `.md-content [class^=btn]{ display:inline-block}`or `text-align: center;` without changing `/* visibility: hidden; */`